# Map search for specific query

Tags: ios, dictionary, geolocation, search-engine

I have a working map based ios app which centers on the users location and move as the user moves. I wish to add functionality to it so that when the map is opened it drops pins where the nearest 'butcheries' are. I can't find an example of such a 'search' query. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways
1) query a web API which delivers those results (i.e. factual.com)
2) forward the query to the local Google maps SDK (some dozen megabytes)